# Is there a bitcoin mining program that works with multple devices, and adds the collective satoshis together?

Tags: mining-pools

I'm very new, and I created this account to ask this question. While at home, we have several unused computers from over the years and I set up 2 computers to run a mining program.

My question is, Is there a program that can add the collective mining efforts together so that they reach the payout threshold faster?

Just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring to pool mining since you mentioned "payout threshold".
You can simply connect all your computers/mining devices to the same mining pool as workers, and the pool will count each worker towards your shares/efforts.